# Amazon Mechanical Turk Command Line Tools - A JNI error has occurred

Tags: command-line, java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install and use Amazon Mechanical Turk Command Line Tools, which I just downloaded from https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/clt

I'm trying to run them from a Administrator Command Prompt in Windows 10.

When I try the getBalance script, I get the following error:

```
c:\mypath\aws-mturk-clt\aws-mturk-clt-1.3.4>bin\getBalance
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/mturk/filter/Filter
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.mturk.filter.Filter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

The error message tells me to check my installation, but there was really nothing to install.

Comment: Are AWS command-line tools not "software"?  I'm setting it up for a single user, not for corporate use.